# How to set up a calendar that shows the due date of the Task records in Lightning?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, tasks, configuration, calendar

The calendar in Lightning does not reflect the tasks that I have. I have over 200 records assigned to me with due dates in each of them but I do not see it in the calendar.

Any idea why is this?

Here's how I set it up.

[image]

Comment: this print-screen shows edit / new calendar. the first stage you have selected an object, did you select the `Task` object? if so, and these tasks are truly yours - this should work

Comment: thank you @ItaiShmida, I was using a different object named Task as well. This works fine now.